Db Concurrency issue with post likes
I have a like method, the method should add users likes records to a post, and also add the like count, this a commom issue for concurrency. what is actually bothering me is the maxRetryAttempts = 50, i dont know exactly if i should retry it forever, or give it a max retry attempts.
The issue is that if i solve this way:
 public async Task<Social> Like(LikeDto dto)
 {
    async Task<bool> likeAndSave(Rating rating, bool isLiked)
    {
        bool like() => rating.Like(_auth.User, rating.OfferId, isLiked);
        var liked = false;

        try
        {
            liked = like();
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            _context.Entry(rating).Reload();
            liked = like();
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //Concurrency conflic my occur again here.
        }

        return liked;
    }
   
    var rating = await _context.Set<Rating>()
        .Include(e => e.Likes.Where(e => e.User.Id == _auth.UserId))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.OfferId == dto.Id);
    var liked = await likeAndSave(rating, dto.Liked);

    return rating.Analytics;
}

Then i refactored the likeAndSave to use retry.
 public async Task<Social> Like(LikeDto dto)
 {
     async Task<(Rating, bool)> likeAndSave(bool isLiked)
     {
         var liked = false;

         var res = await Policies.DbUpdateConcurrencyRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
         {
             var rating = await _context.Set<Rating>()
                    .Include(e => e.Likes.Where(e => e.User.Id == _auth.UserId))
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.OfferId == dto.Id);

             liked = rating.Like(_auth.User, rating.OfferId, isLiked);

             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             return (rating, liked);
         });

         return res;
     }

     var (rating, liked) = await likeAndSave(dto.Liked);

     return rating.Analytics;
 }

Policy Class:
public static class Policies
{
    public static readonly AsyncRetryPolicy DbUpdateConcurrencyRetryPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(50, retryAttempt =>
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds * Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt - 1)));
}

Entities:
public class Post
{
    public Analytics Social { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public List<TRating> Ratings { get; set; } = new();
    public List<TReport> Reports { get; set; } = new();
    public List<TLike> Likes { get; set; } = new();
    public List<TDislike> Dislikes { get; set; } = new();
    public List<TComment> Comments { get; set; } = new();
    public List<TShare> Shares { get; set; } = new();
    public Analytics Analytics { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}

public class Analytics 
{
    public int TotalViews { get; set; }
    public int TotalRatings { get; set; }
    public int TotalReports { get; set; }
    public int TotalLikes { get; set; }
    public int TotalDislikes { get; set; }
    public int TotalShares { get; set; }
    public int TotalComments { get; set; }
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
}

The method is working, fine, just wondering about the retry policy if it would there be anything safer than that.

Ef Core Connection Resiliency

@vusaldev, could you explain it better? how can i solve my issue with the CreateExecutionStrategy? Did not quite understand

It won't help in your current case, but it helpful to create resilent app. Just for knowledge

Using EF Core requires you to read, update, then write. If you drop down to raw sql, or use the new-ish ExecuteUpdate (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant), the database has a better chance of applying the update atomically.

You are having problem of concurrency when two request are trying to update same record at same time.
Couple of solution can work that I'm aware of depends on the level of concurrency.
As per your question we need to do two task

Create a relational record - Who liked the post.(Here you will not face this issue as you are creating/deleting a record every time for a user and
your current optimistic approach should be enough to solve this problem.)

Sum of likes count for a post.


The optimistic approach you are taking works well for really low concurrency or almost no concurrency application.
Here onwards you can chose a approach that suits you. One more thing these approach may not be the best but giving them keeping in mind of the state of application from your question.
You are already using the optimistic approach. You can further also read about this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency.
Other approach you can take is Debouncing the updates.
Debouncing is a technique where you delay processing until a certain time period has elapsed without any new update requests. This approach ensures that rapid updates are consolidated into a single update.
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource> DebounceTokens = new();
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> PostLikes = new();

public async Task UpdateLikesWithDebouncing(int id, bool isLiked, TimeSpan debounceTime)
{
    // Cancel any existing scheduled update for this entity
    if (DebounceTokens.TryGetValue(id, out var existingCts))
    {
        existingCts.Cancel();
        existingCts.Dispose();
    }

    // Create a new cancellation token source for the new update
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    DebounceTokens[id] = cts;

   // Modify this part to handle index to store total incoming likes count smothly.  
    if(isLiked){
        PostLikes[id] += 1;
    }else{
        PostLikes[id] -= 1;
    }

    try
    {
        // Wait for the debounce period
        await Task.Delay(debounceTime, cts.Token);

        // Fetch the entity from the database
        var entity = await dbContext.Posts.FindAsync(id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            entity.LikeCount = PostLikes[id];

            // Save changes to the database
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // The task was canceled, so we skip the update
    }
    finally
    {
        DebounceTokens.TryRemove(id, out _);
        PostLikes.TryRemove(id, out _);
    }
}


Usage
await UpdateEntityWithDebouncing(id, true , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

One more thing you can do to handle the request in queue. we call it Eventual Consistency Strategy.
This can be implemented using an event queue or a background processing mechanism like a message broker (e.g., RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus) or
a background worker (e.g., IHostedService in .NET Core). You can also use in memory queue and process the request one by one through background services.
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<(int Id, bool isLikes)> PostLikesQueue = new();


public class UpdatePostLikesProcessor : BackgroundService
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

   public UpdatePostLikesProcessor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       _dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
   }

   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
       while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           if (PostLikesQueue.TryDequeue(out var isLiked))
           {
               using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

               // Fetch the entity and apply the update
               var entity = await _dbContext.Posts.FindAsync(update.Id);
               if (entity != null)
               {
                   if(isLiked){
                       entity.Likes += entity.Likes;
                   }else{
                       entity.Likes -= entity.Likes;
                   }
                   await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
               }
           }

           // Add a small delay to reduce CPU usage
           await Task.Delay(100, stoppingToken);
       }
   }
}



Yeah, i thought that under high scencarios it could not be a efficient way. I really appreciate your explanations and will test to implement those approaches.
I will also update the question with the entities i am actually using, so if you would like to edit your answer upfront to the specific data in use.
